# Running Linux on Windows because of Python package incompatibility

Tags: python, linux, windows, operating-system, package

I need to install a Python [package](https://github.com/HaseloffLab/CellModeller) that I found on GitHub and it seems to be compatible only with Linux and MacOS. I have Windows 10 and the possibilities that I know of are:

1. Cygwin - but will that solve my problem?
2. VirtualBox - but what do I need to do after installing it?
3. Dual boot - but it's my work laptop and I can't risk any accidents.

What would be the best solution and what are the steps to run Linux on Windows 10 so that I can later install the package?

Comment: WSL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the best solution to me is you installing [WSL for Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

To do so you either need to activate the feature through the Control Panel:

**Control panel** → **Programs** → **Programs and Features** → **Turn Windows features on or off** → scroll down and check **Windows Subsystem for Linux**

Or by executing this Powershell command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

At this point, you can proceed and install a linux distribution package on your Windows10 system! [Ubuntu is available on the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6) for example.

Or you can also install something less conventional, like [Archlinux](https://github.com/yuk7/ArchWSL).

No virtual machine, immediate access to the command line. No dual boot, no Cygwin but a full featured distribution except Xorg. And the Linux subsystem can directly access to your Windows drive out of the box, no need to set up shared folders.

Checkmate! ;)

Answer (score 2):

## WSL (Preferred)

Have a look at WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

After enabling WSL, you will be able to download and install ubuntu from the windows store and have cli access to it. You can then download python on it and then use it to install and run your package.

## Alternative

Another alternative is using docker containers but since dockers share the kernel with the host, docker will have to create and run a linux kernel on your windows host which will run all your other docker images. This is not recommended because it may slow down your machine but docker has other advantages such as isolation.

In the end it just depends on your choice